# Automapper: use interfaces with ITypeConverter

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, interface, automapper

I'm developing a service where I have a method that has as parameter an object where a property is an Interface.

The problem of that interface is that I have a function that wants as parameter an enumerator that I won't will be visible in the service.

So I'd create a class what implement ITypeConverter but I have the problem that I can't make a instance of an Interface (obviusly).
[image: This can't work]

So I create a class and all works:
[image: This works]

I know this is the wrong way, so I want ask what will be the best way to realize that.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 0):

Your convert method should do a check for null on the destination if it's null then create a new DummyUser, something like:

```
Public Class IUser_Converter
    Implements ITypeConverter(Of IUserDto, IUser)

    Public Function Convert (source As IUserDto, destination As IUser, context As ResolutionContext) As IUser
        If(destination Is Nothing)
            destination = New DummyUser()
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```